# Skip Safari when running web-component-tester

Tags: selenium-webdriver, polymer, web-component-tester, polymer-starter-kit

I am trying to work around the known Safari issue in the Selenium Safari driver:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/631

Until there is a new build of the Safari driver I would like to skip Safari when running web-component-tester. Is there a way to do that?

I am working with the polymer-starter-kit 1.0.3 and using `gulp test:local` to run the tests. I found some configuration information on the web-component-tester regarding plugins but I am not sure the information applies to Polymer 1.0.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to pass config to `gulp test:local` right now. There should be a bug filed about that on web-component-tester.

For now, you can use web-component-tester's function directly

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var wct = require('web-component-tester');
gulp.task('test-without-safari', function(done) {
  wct.test({
    plugins: {local: ['chrome', 'firefox'], sauce: false}
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      err = new gutil.PluginError('wct', err, {showStack: true});
    }
    done(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help.